# How to define scheduler at a specific time?

Tags: java, spring, cron, quartz-scheduler, spring-scheduled

I would like to define the spring scheduler (or quartz cron scheduler) at specific times.

For example, I have been given particular times at which a certain job should be run. Those times are 09:00, 12:15, 15:35, 19:05
So as you can see these times are random.

So I cannot schedule them in cron

Is there another way to fire the job at these times specified?

Answer (score 0):

If the times are fixed, you can via Cron even if they seem random. You can try adding entrees in your crontab like:
00 09 * * * USER yourcommande/here
15 12 * * * USER yourjob/here
35 15 * * * USER Nextjob

Synthax is :
mm hh dd MM YY Command

Comment: no. this wont work for me. I want the scheduler to do this and not some person firing the command everytime

Comment: So, you want running differed job only once at a specific (random) time?
May be you need 'at' commande in shell. Something like :
#at -f myjob.sh hh:mm M dd

Answer (score 0):

It's not particuarly elegant, but if these times are always constant you can just have four separate schedules, a cron statement for each.

Comment: No. They are not constant

Comment: If there is no schedule, then how can you have a schedule? I sometimes have an endpoint that triggers a task so all you need to do an HTTP request but again, that would be have to be done manually...